# Словообразование глагола "жглась"

Tags: словообразование, глаголы

Каков способ словообразования глагола "жглась"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Жечься - от жечь с помощью постфикса -СЯ - аффиксальный (суффиксальный - в школе, постфиксальный)

Answer (score 1):

Форма "жглась" является **формой прошедшего времени** глагола "жечься": жечь/ся ―
 жг/л/а/сь, способ образования суффиксальный, А ― окончание ж.р.

**Глагол "жечься" образуется от глагола "жечь"**, способ образования суффиксальный (или постфиксальный): жечь ― жечь/ся.

Постфикс СЯ является самостоятельным словообразовательным элементом с общим значением устранения переходности и дополнительным значением способности к действию.